# How to restrict the access IP of VPN users

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, pptp

I configured a VPN server(PPTP), and it works well. However, I just want people having IPs of specific address range can access to this server. So, what could I do to control or restrict the access IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you configure your iptables firewall to allow only specific addresses for your VPN users and drop all others?

It should look like:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -s <your_vpn_pool> <your_targer_ip's> -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -p tcp -s <your_vpn_pool> -j REJECT
```

Look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/easy-setup-of-iptables-on-your-new-linux-server.html) for more examples about iptables config.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just whitelist instead?

Comment: Actually I am a fresher and not familiar with pptp whitelist, could you give me more info?